# Using tqdm with a class and arguments

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

Im attemting to use tqdm and multiprocessing to run through a range of values and pass that same range value into the class im calling as an argument. I can't seem to find anything useful online on how to pass arguments of the iteration into the fuction call (in my case im calling a class function), Im hoping someone else may have an idea?

```
with Pool(processes=8) as p:
    max_ = 5
    with tqdm(total=max_) as pbar:
        for k, _ in tqdm(o.function('iterable-here'), range(1, max_)):
            pbar.update()
```